# How to convert column of range into median or mean in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column stating values in range as follows.

```
a <- c("10-15","20-25","30-35","35-40")
df <- data.frame(a)
```

I want to convert this range into median in new column. How can i do this in R.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```r
df$mean <- sapply(strsplit(df$a, '-'), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))
#       a mean
# 1 10-15 12.5
# 2 20-25 22.5
# 3 30-35 32.5
# 4 35-40 37.5
```